# Algorithm to generate Metro UI style Tiles based on Menu Items?

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-metro

I am making an Angular App. I want the main menu to look like the tiles in Windows 8.
Now I want an algorithm that will automatically generate a pattern for tiles where some tiles are bigger than others.

So basically I would like to create a component to whichI will provide a dataSource as an array of Json objects containg menu-items.

and then the component should layout tiles in a fashion that it accommodates all of them.

How should I go about it?

I am learning angularjs. Can I avoid using jQuery plugins and do without it ?

Comment: Create a directive in angularjs and use Twitter Bootstrap to layout tiles like metro UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can handle this without an external JS library (mansory, isotope). But there is another trap you may step into. Angular is going to populate your DOM with promises, not tiles. Trouble is that Mansory/Isotope is trying to (re)calculate the new layout without having all data (width, height) necessary. You should use $timeout to sync Angular scope with external library.

```
isotopeApp.directive('isotope', function ($timeout) {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('postAdded', function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                element.isotope('reloadItems').isotope({
                    sortBy: 'original-order'
                });
            })
        })
    }
};
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/8Qmry/

Comment: So this design/layout has a name :'Mansory'.
I never knew it!
I will try something.

Answer (score 2):

Coming late to the party here, but if you don't want the DOM littered with a whole bunch of unnecessary digest cycles and spped up the reactiveness of the effect, adding 'false' to the timeout stops the digest cycles from going nuts and with larger datasets, speeds things up exponentially:

```
isotopeApp.directive('isotope', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('postAdded', function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.isotope('reloadItems').isotope({
                        sortBy: 'original-order'
                    });
                }, false)
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Not changing much but a big performance boost.